# Connecting to wifi router through wifi disables/breaks ethernet connections

Tags: wireless-networking, router, macbook-pro

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro and a TP-link wifi router (C3200US). When I connect with any other device in the house by wifi - everything works. Including a 2013 MBP, 2017 MBP and 2016 MB Air + tablets and phones.

When I connect via ethernet from my 2018 MBP, it works fine, When I switch on wifi for the 2018 MBP and connect to the wifi router, ALL ethernet connections are disabled - so no other device can connect and of course I lose my connection to my cable modem and so no internet.

Any ideas what is causing this? I've reset the router - no luck. Also, Apple repaired, then replaced the first 2018 MBP that had this issue - and the replacement - a brand new one shosw the same issue.

Next ideas are:- generate a new MAC address for the MBP, or try turning off the Wifi on the router and use a separate access point to provide the wifi for the house.

Comment: Have you tried updating the firmware running on the router?

Comment: i think it is up to date but will reconfirm - thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `ifconfig` on your 2018 MBP? I'm wondering if you've managed to bridge Ethernet and Wi-Fi, creating a network loop. Does the failure only happen when you keep the Ethernet connected to the 2018 MBP at the same time as it is on the network via Wi-Fi? Does the problem go away if you disconnect the Ethernet cable from the MBP?

Comment: while ethernet is connected there is no issue. When I disconnect Ethernet and turn on wifi,  then the problem occurs.

Answer (score -1):

If I had a guess, it's because your 2018 MBP has a static IP that is the same as the router. Once you connect, there's an IP conflict. Likely it's best to enable DHCP on the 2018 MBP. The router likely has a log that will say something like "duplicate ip address detected".

Who knows what wacky routing will take place if you plugging the 2018 MBP (or something else) into the port where the internet is supposed to go.

Comment: TY, The wifi is set to DHCP - I do understand a static IP and I do use them on other machines - but this laptop gets its IP address for the Router's DHCP And I can see it in the routers DHCP IP List.  Also I am definitely *not* plugging anything into the router's Internet port except the cable to the cable modem, so not sure what you meant by this.

Comment: It isn't really an answer to your question...